# iMac 27" 2009 - GPU

Tags: imac, gpu

I have a iMac 27" 2009, and I'm working on image files in PS that are 2/3gig, the computer is only just handling it. Can I up grade the GPU? would that help?

Comment: How much ram do you have?  How much memory in current GPU?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Assuming you have a 'Late 2009' iMac, check out [iMac Intel 27" (Late 2009 or Mid 2010) Graphics Card Replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+27-Inch+(Late+2009+or+Mid+2010)+Graphics+Card+Replacement/9553).

Before, upgrading your GPU, start by:

1. Maⅺng out your RAM (up to 32 GB). I like [OWC Memory Upgrades](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/iMac/DDR3_21.5_27).
2. If you're running a hard disk drive (HDD), upgrade to an SSD. Again, I prefer, [OWC Solid State Drives](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/imac-27-inch/late-2009).
3. Upgrade to [macOS High Sierra 10.13.6](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201634) - ([⤓ .dmg](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1970?locale=en_CA)).
4. If it's still necessary, upgrade GPU.